# real root of $x^4-x^3\sin x-x^2\cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many real roots does $x^4-x^3\sin x-x^2\cos x$ have?

---

I want to make derivative for such equation, but it seems doesn't work for solving problem.

Comment: Please use $\sin, \cos$ etc. for functions to improve readability: `\sin, \cos`

Comment: @AlexR Oh, come on! It's not like anyone's sitting at their desk, looking at that and thinking that $sin$ means $s \times i \times n.$

Comment: @alexqwx Okay read $sinx cosy tanz$ and rant again.

Comment: @alexqwx: Nevertheless, it's easier to read with that edit. It's perfectly clear what I mean by, "Its' eaSIEr to REAd WiTh THaT ed1t," but the former is still an improvement over the latter.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that the derivative "doesn't work"?

Comment: @AlexR $sin(x) \ cos(y) \ tan(z)$ is as easy to read as $\sin(x) \cos(y) \tan(z)$. You're cheating by using no spacing between functions!

Comment: Apart from being readable, your question has to be understandable too. I don't think you'd have trouble finding it's derivative, so what does that last line mean?

Comment: @Amzoti But u can't prove these are real roots.

Comment: @UserX Edited. sorry

Comment: Well, yea, evaluating its derivative isn't gonna help you. You can factor $x^2$ but then you're left with numerical methods only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a root at $x=0$. Now we can divide by $x^2$, getting $f(x)=x^2 - x \sin x - \cos x$.

$f (0) = -1 < 0$, but the term $x^2$ makes $f (x) > 0$ for large x, so there are two zeroes.

$f' (x)=2x-\sin x - x\cos x + \sin x = 2x - x \cos x = x (2 - \cos x)$. This is only zero when $x=0$, so f (x) has just two zeroes, and the original function has three.